# Why is Snake covered in blood even after a shower?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So I have been playing MGS 5 for a while now and understand the mechanic of being covered in blood after a battle where you get hit or close combat kill an enemy. This can be removed by changing the uniform or taking a shower.....however I have just come across the point where I cannot remove the blood on Snake and it is rather annoying to me. Is there a way to remove this blood? Just for reference I am on misison 20, and have tried changing outfits and taking a shower.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a bug. I'm assuming you're too far past this happening to go back to an earlier point in time to when this didn't happen?

Comment: @DangerZone - Nope, this is not a bug. There is a hidden statistic in the game which is called demon points. If that reaches a high enough level, the shrapnel horn grows and you can't wash off blood.

Comment: @5pike - Interesting... How do you get (or lose) demon points? Or if you have a source on this, that would help. You should also post that info an an answer.

Comment: @DangerZone - [Here is a source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72466130)

Comment: @5pike Huh I wish they would mention this somewhere in the game....Interesting, i guess that makes sense though

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From what I've read [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72466130), the only way to get the blood off of snake, is by lowering your "Demon level".

> 10- Can I shower off Demon Snake's blood?
>
> No, it can only be removed by lowering your Demon Level.

You can lower your Demon level via the following actions:

> DPG06-----Losing Demon Points-----
>
> The following is a list of actions the players can perform to decrease their Demon Points, grouped by category:
>
> ---Fulton extractions
>
> -30 - Fulton extract a common animal
>   -30 - Fulton extract a critically wounded enemy soldier
>   -30 - Fulton extract a puppet soldier via helicopter
>   -30 - Fulton extract a critically wounded enemy soldier
>   -30 - Fulton extract a Skull
>   -60 - Fulton extract a rare animal
>   -60 - Fulton extract a Diamond Dogs staff member
>   -60 - Fulton extract a prisoner
>   -120 - Fulton extract a child
>   -120 - Fulton extract a very rare or extremely rare animal
>
> ---Extractions by helicopter
>
> -30 - Extract an enemy soldier via helicopter
>   -60 - Extract a puppet soldier via helicopter
>   -60 - Extract a critically wounded enemy via helicopter
>   -60 - Extract Quiet via helicopter
>   -120 - Extract a VIP or prisoner via helicopter
>   -120 - Extract a Diamond Dogs staff member via helicopter
>   -240 - Extract a child via helicopter
>
> ---Trophies
>
> -1,000 - Earn the "Cry Havoc" trophy
>   -1,000 - Earn the "Speechless" trophy
>   -5,000 - Earn the "Cleared" trophy
>   -5,000 - Earn the "Trusty Steed" trophy
>   -5,000 - Earn the "Man's Best Friend" trophy
>   -5,000 - Earn the "War Buddy" trophy
>   -5,000 - Earn the "Reminiscence" trophy
>   -10,000 - Earn the "Conservation" trophy
>
> ---Other
>
> -300 - Visit the Animal Conservation Platform
>   -1,000 - Dispose of a nuclear weapon
>   -30,000 - Dispose of ten nuclear weapons

And here are the actions that can raise your Demon level:

> DPG05-----Earning Demon Points-----
>
> The following is a list of actions the players can perform to increase their Demon Points, grouped by category:
>
> ---Fulton extractions
>
> +20 - Fail the fulton extraction of an animal
>   +60 - Fail the fulton extraction of an enemy soldier
>
> ---Assassinations
>
> +20 - Kill an animal
>   +60 - Kill an enemy soldier
>   +90 - Kill a Diamond Dogs staff member held hostage
>   +100 - Kill a prisoner
>   +120 - Kill a critically wounded enemy soldier
>   +180 - Kill a Diamond Dogs staff member
>
> ---Assassinations via fire damage
>
> +40 - Kill an animal with fire damage
>   +120 - Kill an enemy soldier with fire damage
>   +180 - Kill one of your Diamond Dogs staff members held hostage with fire damage
>   +200 - Kill a prisoner with fire damage
>
> ---Buddies
>
> +75 - Destroy D-Walker
>   +150 - Critically wound D-Dog, D-Horse or Quiet
>
> ---Other
>
> +30 - Critically wound an enemy soldier
>   +60 - Lose a staff member held hostage by aborting mission 22 (+60 each)
>   +150 - Destroy a support helicopter
>   +50,000 - Develop a nuclear weapon

Comment: This is really cool! (Or annoying, if you don't like the new look..) Thanks or the info.

Comment: I guess they felt like they had to put in a "penalty" for using too many lethal weapons, since MGSV is much more tolerant of a "run-and-gun" playstyle than previous games in my opinion. And, holy Christ, I'm glad I decided not to develop any nukes yet.

Comment: Could you also add the actions that *add* Demon points, so we know which actions to avoid? Killing a soldier obviously awards Demon points, but what about killing a Skull or blowing up an enemy gunship, etc.?

Comment: Other than venom's physical appearance- are there any other factors effected by the demon level?

Comment: @GP89 - From what I've read, no.

Comment: @GP89 Snake leaves bloody footprints, which can be easily seen by guards.

Comment: @Tom - Oh yeah, that's true. I'm reading that not every guard will notice the footprints. It seems that higher ranked guards have a bigger chance at spotting them.

Comment: Huh? Who's footprints are these?

Comment: how can you fullton extract a puppet soldier via helicopter?

Comment: @GP98 Big Boss is soaked in blood - so those are his footprints.

Answer (score 7):

There is a hidden stat in the game - Demon points, which are basically the opposite of heroism. Demon points are gained in various ways - Killing animals, enemy soldiers, prisoners etc.

These points accumulate behind the scenes and are not viewable. When your demon points get too high you will see changes such as being permenantly covered in blood and the horn on your head growing in size.

Demon points can be reduced by doing things like extracting animals, children and enemy soldiers via helicopter.

Here is a pretty in depth guide to explain things in more detail: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72466130