# Are there any character effects for having no/low [HIDDEN STAT]

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I read this question: [Why is Snake covered in blood even after a shower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237263/why-is-snake-covered-in-blood-even-after-a-shower) and thought the mechanic was really cool.

Is it possible to have negative demon points, and are there any physical changes that happen if you're a good person?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say even if demon points could go negative, I would assume there is no physical change. Otherwise there are a ton of players who play with excellent stealth (see how to lose points in that post) and surely someone would have noticed by now. But that's just my theory.

Comment: Er, not sure who edited this, but it seems silly to spoil that there are hidden stats in the game when before the title didn't.

Answer (score -1):

What you're referring to is generally called "Demon Snake".  This is what happens when your demon points get to be rather high.  The opposite of the demon points are **Heroism points**.

Demon points get reduced as you gain Heroism points so instead of making demon points go negative it stops at zero.  Once you gain a certain amount of heroism points after reducing your demon points to zero you get a similar "visual difference".  Since that point system is meant to be the opposite of "becoming a demon" (i.e. A large and being covered in blood) your horn shrinks in size until it is more of a bump.

[This wikia page has a great explanation of the entire demon points and heroism points system.](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Demon_Points)

Comment: This is incorrect: Demon points are not the opposite of Heroism points. Certain actions will give you Demon points while reducing your Heroism points, or vice versa, but not all of them. For example, interrogating a soldier gives you 5 Heroism points, but it does not lower or affect your Demon points at all. Also, according to your link, your horn only shrinks in size if it had previously grew from the baseline. If you have no demon points, your horn does not get any smaller than it was at the start of the game.